# Confused about static methods with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm calling the following from my controller:

```
public ViewResult Index()
{
    var users = SecurityHelpers.GetAllStaff();
    return View(users);
}
```

The method I'm calling to get all my users looks like this:

```
public class SecurityHelpers
{
    private static Context db = new Context();

    public static IQueryable<ApplicationUser> GetAllStaff()
    {            
        var users = db.Users
                .OrderBy(x => x.FirstName).ThenBy(x => x.LastName);            
        return users;
    }
}
```

My problem is that when I modify a staff member, such as by setting a disabled boolean, the method is bring back their old data (so the disabled user is still enabled).  I think this is because static functions are cached until the app pool recycles?

Is there a way to also get the latest data from this method without making it non-static? (as there is a lot of code that will need to be changed to instatiate the object each time, and I don't think that's the right architecture)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I think this is because static functions are cached until the app pool recycles

No. The problem is that you use a long-lived context (`db`) that you keep alive forever in a static variable, and this context is caching all the entities you are querying.

There is a way to refresh the cached entities so that you don't get stale values, but the real problem here is that you really shouldn't be keeping a long-lived context like that.  It comes with this problem of stale data, and as the cache grows, you will also start noticing bad performance.

Notice what the [documentation says about how entities are returned from queries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj573936) (emphasis mine):

> When results are returned from the database, objects that do not exist in the context are attached to the context. ***If an object is already in the context, the existing object is returned***

One viable alternative is to create the context as needed. Example:

```
public class SecurityHelpers
{
    public static IList<ApplicationUser> GetAllStaff()
    {            
        using(var db = new Context())
        {
            var users = db.Users
                    .OrderBy(x => x.FirstName).ThenBy(x => x.LastName)
                    .ToList();            
            return users;
        }
    }
}
```

Depending on how your application is architected, you may be able to set it up so that you have a context instance per request instead. That would be even better IMO.  However you decide to do it, don't use a singleton context!

Answer (score 0):

Static Entity Framework object also can cause **loss of data**. It might allow the program to remove records that source of FK even you have set the DELETE_RULE - No Action in the DB.

That's why it is mandatory to use this code(user sstan's):

```
    using(var db = new Context())
    {
        var users = db.Users
                .OrderBy(x => x.FirstName).ThenBy(x => x.LastName)
                .ToList();            
        return users;
    }
```